# Zoom in Anychart using anychart.resource()

Tags: anychart

I'm converting from using anychart.ganttResource() to using anychart.resource(), since I need overlapping tasks for my resources.
In anychart.ganttResource() we used zoomTo to get the timeline to match filter on the period shown, but according to the api reference this only Works for Gantt or Maps.
Do anyone know how to set "an end date" for timeline in resource, or how to control to timeline / calendar ?
Regards Anja

EDIT:
Using https://playground.anychart.com/gallery/8.0.1/Gantt_Charts/Server_Status_List I figured out how to get overlapping task in a ganttresource chart

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as December of 2017 AnyChart 8.0.1 doesn't provide such feature for Resource Chart. After the chart loading, visible range of the Resource chart is always anchored to the beginning of the xScale.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. If I use the Gantt Ressource Chart, can I then have overlapping tasks for the resources? (like in this https://playground.anychart.com/gallery/8.0.1/Resource_Charts/Development_Team_Plan_(Time_Tracking_On) ), If so  can you provide me with an example?

Comment: Actually, the resource chart in this demo doesn't contain overlapping tasks. Every activity represents how many hours per day any resource is busy. Several activities stacked in a column means that this resource is busy several times by different tasks and during different periods of a day. Gantt resource provides overlapping, two overlapped periods look like a single one. An example of such behavior you may find in this example - https://jsfiddle.net/v2gwp7L7/ .   Server1 actually has three periods, but the 1st and 2nd are overlapped.